# *char into main and *char into a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, initialization, strcpy

The two following codes are similar but the first has a structure, the second not.

Why this code works (with no warnings)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct prova
{
    char *stringa;
};

int main()
{
    struct prova p;

    strcpy (p.stringa, "example\0");

    printf("%s\n", p.stringa);

    return 0;
}
```

But the following code doesn't work?

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

With this warning:

`code.c: In function ‘main’:
code.c:8:9: warning: ‘stringa’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  strcpy (stringa, "example\0");`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *stringa;

    strcpy (stringa, "example\0");

    printf("%s\n", stringa);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are not allocating memory for `stringa`. It might work or not, but still both are wrong. Try putting a bigger string in first example.

Comment: Yes, I know that is wrong, but I don't understand why the first code works! (Thank you for the answer!)

Comment: Because of internals on how memory is allocated. First example probably allocates more memory than second, or on a different way. This is compiler-specific, probably using a different compiler/platform will yield different results.

Comment: _first code works!_  only lucky.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'd regard any version of this code that works as being a stroke of misfortune.

Comment: i am not sure why you are showing two wrong ways and letting us decide which is worse? - fun?

Comment: @user Is my code edit accurate. Your original question contained a program that did not compile.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not notice it to be dead and I thought the bullet does not hit.

Comment: @claptrap Because at the first I wrote the first code for error, and it worked, and I wanted to understand why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is correct because you copy to an address specified by an uninitialized variable. Therefore both programs invoke undefined behaviour.

The fact that one of the programs works is down to pure chance. One possible form of undefined behaviour is that your program runs correctly.

You need to initialize the pointer to refer to a sufficiently sized block of memory. For instance:

```
char *stringa = malloc(8);
```

Note that you do not need to add a null terminator to a string literal. That is implicit. So, given this memory allocation you can then write:

```
strcpy(stringa, "example");
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! But this: `char *stringa = malloc(10*sizeof(char));` it's the same of this: `char stringa[10];`?

Comment: @user No it is not. The former allocates dynamic memory that must be freed with a call to `free` to avoid leakage. The latter allocates storage automatically and the character array only lives as long as the containing scope. Note that `sizeof(char)` is by definition equal to 1 and so idiomatic C omits it. If you are going to allocate automatically you would write `char stringa[] = "example";`

Comment: If beforehand I don't know the size I use malloc, but if i know the size what is the reason to choose between (for example) `char *stringa = malloc(10);` or `char stringa[10];`?

Comment: If you only know length at runtime, you have to use malloc. Lifetime issues can also force malloc.

Comment: You can only use char s[10] if the 10 is known at compile time.

Comment: Ok now I understand (the problem is my bad English...). But if i know length at compile-time, I must use always `s[10];` or it may happen that it's better to use malloc?

Comment: You can use malloc. And sometimes you need to. If you need to return the string when the function ends, you cannot use a local variable. That's what I mean about scope.

Comment: Ok thank you! Now I do a new question about this, because I can't post a multiple-lines code into a comment. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the string some memory for it copy the characters to.

Use `malloc`

besides the first example does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

struct prova
{
    char *stringa;
};

int main()
{
    struct prova p;

```
strcpy (p.stringa, "example\0");
```

notice that p.stringa points to nowhere in particular but you copy to it.